# Show only nulls in a straight table in QlikView

Tags: qlikview

I have a table with 2 columns, `ID` and `NC`.

`ID` is unique and `NC` contains values (some values can be null).

I need show only `null` values in a straight table.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a **calculated dimension** in the straight table, with an expression similar to the following:

```
=if(isnull(NC),ID,null())
```

Ensure that you also check the option marked `Supress When Value Is Null` and that will remove the null row from the table.

[image: Calculated Dimension]

For example, my test data set is as follows:

```
ID  NC
------
A   1
B   2
C   NULL 
D   3
E   4
```

The result (original on left), and calculated dimension table on the right:

[image: before and after the calculated dimension]